# Entity Framework increment memory after every call context to list

Tags: c#

I have a problem with Entity Framework Core.

I made an admin panel for monitoring in "Blazor Server" with stardate and to date users choose and
every click search with from date && to date memory increment 200mb, 300mb, 400mb, 1gb..

I need don't increment memory after call dbcontext..

Method call:

```
var data = await Task.Run(() => Service.GetJasminData(fromdate, todate)?.OrderBy(x => x.SendDate).ToList());
```

Method:

```
protected readonly ApplicationDBContext _dBContext;

public SmsService(ApplicationDBContext _db)
{
    _dBContext = _db;
}

public List<Sms> GetJasminData(DateTime fromdate, DateTime todate, int count = 30)
{
    return _dBContext.Jasmin.Where(x => x.SendDate >= fromdate && x.SendDate <= todate).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Do not use `Task.Run` in web applications, use the Async version of `EF` methods instead. Another thing to consider is whether you have a plan for how to dispose of objects like `DbContext`
 That's because the Blazor server works differently from web applications, and objects aren't automatically disposed after they're created

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you retrieve data from the database, by default EF starts to track this information so it can know what has been changed to update the data during a `SaveChanges()` call.

You may have some memory leak issue, it is worth taking a look if your dbcontext is behaving correctly, probably not since the memory usage seems to be increasing. Blazor Server can be tricky since it deals in a very different way with calls. How are you registering the Context injection?

One approach you could take is to use `AsNoTracking()`, this will prevent EF from tracking your entities which will decrease your memory usage, for a read-only call that's the best approach.

I also recommend you avoid `Task.Run()`, EF has some built-in methods that are ready to deal with async calls and have internally optimized.

#### Repository methods

```
 protected readonly ApplicationDBContext _dBContext;

 public SmsService(ApplicationDBContext _db)
 {
      _dBContext = _db;
 }

 public async Task<List<Sms>> GetJasminData(DateTime fromdate, DateTime todate, int count = 30)
 {
     return await _dBContext.Jasmin.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.SendDate >= fromdate && x.SendDate <= todate).ToListAsync();
 }
```

### method call

```
 var data = await Service.GetJasminData(fromdate, todate)?.OrderBy(x => x.SendDate).ToList();
```

Thats something that may worth the reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Don't worked.................

Comment: How are you registering your DbContext on DI container?

Comment: protected async Task SearchFilter()
    {

        if (fromdate != DateTime.MinValue && todate != DateTime.MinValue && string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
        {
            //SplitData(Service.GetAll().Where(x => x.SendDate >= fromdate && x.SendDate <= todate)?.OrderBy(x => x.SendDate)?.Take(40).ToList());
            var hasData = await Task.Run(() => Service.GetJasminData(fromdate, todate)?.OrderBy(x => x.SendDate).ToList());

Comment: I mean at your Startup or Program.cs class

Answer (score 0):

**Page Code**

```
  protected async Task SearchFilter()
{

    if (fromdate != DateTime.MinValue && todate != DateTime.MinValue && string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
    {
        //SplitData(Service.GetAll().Where(x => x.SendDate >= fromdate && x.SendDate <= todate)?.OrderBy(x => x.SendDate)?.Take(40).ToList());
        var hasData = await Task.Run(() => Service.GetJasminData(fromdate, todate)?.OrderBy(x => x.SendDate).ToList());
        if (hasData != null)
        {
            SplitData(hasData);
        }
        fromdate = DateTime.MinValue;
    }
    else if (fromdate != DateTime.MinValue && todate != DateTime.MinValue && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
    {
        var hasData = await Task.Run(() => Service.GetJasminData(fromdate, todate).Where(x => x.ToString().Contains(searchText)).ToList());

        if (hasData != null)
        {
            SplitData(hasData);
        }
    }
    else if ((fromdate == DateTime.MinValue || todate == DateTime.MinValue) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
    {
        var hasData = await Task.Run(() => Service.GetAllByText(searchText).ToList());
        if (hasData != null)
        {
            SplitData(hasData);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Do not post an answer with merely codes. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question